# javascript on mouseover add and remove class

Tags: javascript, html, css

Very first question on Stack Overflow, regarding Vanilla Javascript.

I have four links in an unordered list. I have set up a mouseover event on each `<li>` by using forEach.
When I hover over the element I add a css pseudo class of `::after` to the element, which displays a small css rectangle underneath the hovered element.
When I move my mouse directly downward off the element and off the `<ul>`,  the the Css pseudo class of `::after` gets removed and the rectangle disappears, which is exactly what I want. Except if I move my mouse directly from one link element  to another element to the left or right, the previous link element's css pseudo class of `::after` still remains, so the square remains.

Below is some sample code. Any insights would be highly appreciated.

```js
navigationMouseOver();

function navScroll() {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
      document.querySelector(".contact-info2").classList.add("visible");
    } else {
      document.querySelector(".contact-info2").classList.remove("visible");
    }
  })

}

function navigationMouseOver() {
  let navLi = document.querySelectorAll(".link");

  navLi.forEach(function(element) {

    element.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
      let link = e.currentTarget;
      let linkText = e.currentTarget.textContent;
      console.log(linkText);
      const subMenu = document.querySelector(".sub-menu");
      const arrow = document.querySelector(".arrow");

      let elementPos = link.getBoundingClientRect();

      let elementTop = elementPos.top - 50;
      let elementWidth = elementPos.width;
      let elementBottom = elementPos.bottom - 10;
      let elementCenter = (elementPos.left + elementPos.right) / 2;

      let trueCenter = elementCenter - elementWidth;

      let arrowW = arrow.clientWidth;
      let arrowCenter = elementCenter - arrowW;
      element.classList.add("after");
      subMenu.classList.add("show");

      arrow.style.bottom = `${elementBottom} px`
      arrow.style.left = `${arrowCenter}px`
      subMenu.style.top = `${elementBottom}px`;
      subMenu.style.left = `${trueCenter}px`;

      subMenu.innerHTML = "Hallo";
      navMouseOver(element)
    })
  })
}

function navMouseOver(element) {
  let subMenu = document.querySelector(".sub-menu")
  let banner = document.querySelector(".banner");

  banner.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {

    if (!e.target.classList.contains("link")) {
      subMenu.classList.remove("show");
      element.classList.remove("after");
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.banner-nav li.after::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  top: - 20px;
  left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
  <div class="banner-logo">
    <h1 class="logo-text"> Logo</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="banner-nav ">
    <ul class="nav-ul ">
      <a href="#"></a>
      <li class="link"> Gallery </li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li class="link"> Products</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li class="link"> About </li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li class="link"> Contact </li>
      </a>

    </ul>

  </div>
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <div class="sub-menu"></div>

</section>
```

Comment: To make things appear and disappear with Javascript, I usually use `classList.toggle`. Maybe that can work for you to? And maybe use the `onmouseout` event, so Javascript knows when your mouse leaves the element? (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp)

Comment: Your code contains malformed HTML. `<ul>`/`<ol>` may not be parents of `<a>`. Also, I don't see you using `<a>` as an anchor. Why use it, then?

Comment: Hey I added your code in a stack snippet, if you [edit] you can see malformed HTML highlighted in red. Please fix those.

Comment: Welcome! Stackoverflow has a lot of good ways to format your questions, answers and comments https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help It's very useful to use formatting like `::after` using ``` backticks etc. to make text more legible. Good formatting helps others easily understand what you're trying to say, especially when it comes to code and other *technical* stuff. Questions that are easy to read are also easier to answer.

Comment: Thank you fo for the feedback. I have not set up the <a> tags yet, but they will be part of my setup in the end.

Comment: @ Oskar Grosse, I fixed the malformed HTML,thank you.

Comment: @ CervEd. I will go over those rules again,thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript for this. You can combine `:hover` pseudo class with `::after` like this:

`.banner-nav li:hover::after {}`

```css
.banner-nav li:hover::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  top: - 20px;
  left: 40%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
  <div class="banner-logo">
    <h1 class="logo-text"> Logo</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="banner-nav ">
    <ul class="nav-ul ">
      <a href="#"></a>
      <li class="link"> Gallery </li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li class="link"> Products</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li class="link"> About </li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li class="link"> Contact </li>
      </a>

    </ul>

  </div>
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <div class="sub-menu"></div>

</section>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I over complicated it with Javascript. Thank you.